# Third party API returned time string format confirm, like '2019-07-04T01:08:31.1953626+00:00'

Tags: api, time, backend, utc

This is a simple question, In my application I get a time string from an API, its format is as following:

```
2019-07-04T01:08:31.1953626+00:00
```

I'm not so sure about the part after `hh:mm:ss`, for example in this case is `1953626+00:00`, what is this?

By JS API of `toISOString`, the time string format is something like: `2019-07-04T08:29:01.349Z` where the ending part is the milliseconds. In my application, I need to handle some logic based on the time string return by the API shown above, so I need to confirm its meaning.

Note: Someone said it's the CPU tick, not sure. I just want to confirm is it some general convention. Thank you.

Comment: What does the API documentation say?

Comment: No doc, no explain. I just want to confirm is it some general convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ISO 8601

Your input strings are both in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

ISO 8601 is the modern protocol for serializing date-time values as text. These formats minimize the use of English. They are easy to parse by machine. And they are easy to read by humans across cultures.

Newer standards specify ISO 8601 for date-times. ISO 8601 supplants the terrible formats used in older protocols such as seen in email headers.

### Fractional second

The `.1953626` represents a fractional seconds.

Using 7 digits is unusual. Is that a typo? Usually a fractional second is made up of 3, 6, or 9 digits, for a resolution of milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds.

### Offset-from-UTC

The `+00:00` means the date and time-of-day are meant to be interpreted as being zero hours-minutes-seconds ahead of UTC. In other words, at UTC itself.

Ditto for `Z`. The letter is pronounced “Zulu”, and means an offset of `+00:00`.

Comment: thank you  for your input. And it's not a typo. I also see 6 digits in the api return data.